# Excel Macro to combine cells of data when data matches in another column

Tags: vba, excel

The best way I can explain my problem is by showing a few screenshots.

I need to turn data like this:

[[image: BEfore Data]

Into something that displays like this:

After Data
[image: AFter Data]

There are multiple part numbers in the file, and I need the macro to take all the data from a matching part number and transform the data into what is displayed in the second image. All the part numbers are grouped with their data together, so it wouldn't need to run the loop through the top every single time, but adding to the entries with each new piece of data. Something also needs to be done for the years as well, because the way the data is presented, is in a range of years, and I need an entry for each year in that range.

Additional Information:

I am using this data for prep for category data for a BigCommerce site, that is working with a year/make/model plugin on the site, to create a vehicle lookup system. Thus in order for the user to look up their vehicle accurately the categories need to be listed the way they are in the second picture, which needs to be the result of the macro.

I thank anyone who takes the time to look into this, it will cut down the time I spend doing this manually by a huge amount.

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Agreed, however if there is anything anyone can provide that might point me in the right direction as to how it would need to be laid out, I can then look at the individual bits and put it together on my own. I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: It kind of looks like you're just connecting your data in one long string, yeah?

Comment: Pretty much, but it's more than a simple concatenation, mostly because of the years, and the fact that some values will be duplicated and they don't need to be in there twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a formula (without actual VBA):

1. In cell F2 write: `="YMM/"&C2&"/"&D2&"/"&E2&";"`
2. In cell F3 write: `=F2&"YMM/"&C3&"/"&D3&"/"&E3&";"`
3. drag down the formula in F3 until the last row.
4. The last row will contain the entire string of all vehicles.

[image]

I just noticed you may have duplicate values. You can use the built in [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) feature to remove those before using the above technique.

Comment: That gets seriously close to what I need, my only concern is the years. I need to find a way to expand on what you have here, to include the years inside the "Start Year" and "End Year" as well, so they have their own entries in there. Otherwise some vehicle years might get missed.

Comment: @Zeph - to be clear, if the start and end year are different, you want to see in effect, two sets for that line? So for the 3rd line, you want to see `YMM/2007/Dodge/Caliber;YMM/2010/Dodge/Calibur`?

Comment: Essentially if it is a 2012-2015 vehicle, it would show YMM/2012/Dodge/Ram 1500;YMM/2013/Dodge/Ram 1500;YMM/2014/Dodge/Ram 1500;YMM/2012/Dodge/Ram 1500;  That's that part that is getting me stuck in doing anything automated about this.

Comment: @Zeph - Ouch. That requires VBA, I think. If you make attempts to code it we'll be happy to help where you may be stuck. That said, this formula approach should start to give you a sense of *how* to structure the code

Comment: Thank you Scott. At the very least what I wanted to gain from this post was knowing where I needed to look, or how to word my problem to be able to teach myself how to write the macro I require. I have no issues learning code or languages I don't yet know, just lacked a good foundation to get me started.